# Image of a linear combination by a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Take $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $f(x) < f(y)$ and let $L = \{\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y$ : $\alpha \in [0,1]\}$ be the straight line between $x$ and $y$. Is it true that the continuity of $f$ implies that $f(L) \subset [f(x), f(y)]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Take $f(x)=x^2$, $x=-1$ and $y=2$.

We have that $f(x)=1<4=f(y)$, $L=[-1,2]$ and $[f(x),f(y)]=[1,4]$.

Now, $0\in L$ but $f(0)=0\notin [f(x),f(y)]$.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not true. Take $f = x^2-1$, $x = -1$ and $y = 1$. Then $[f(x),f(y)] = \{0 \}$ but $f(L)$ is not contained in this.